# Substitution goes wrong while evaluating $\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Im aware this integral has been evaluated here before, i started with
$$\int _0^{\infty}\frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=2\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx+2G$$
Solving the integral on the left is very easy, then solving for the other one gets its value but the main point of my question comes from the substitution $ x=\frac{1-t}{1+t}$
$$I=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2}\:dx=\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+t^2\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt+\ln \left(2\right)\int _0^1\frac{1}{1+t^2}\:dt-2\int _0^1\frac{\ln \left(1+t\right)}{1+t^2}\:dt$$
And $I$ cancels out, can anyone tell me whats happening here?

Comment: What are the bounds for $t$ ?

Comment: 0 to 1 as well, see $\frac{1-x}{1+x}\rightarrow \frac{1-1}{1+1}=0,\frac{1-x}{1+x}\rightarrow \:\frac{1-0}{1+0}=1$

Comment: then $dx=-\frac{2}{\left(1+t\right)^2}\:dt$ where the- sign is used to flip the bounds

Comment: You have $t=\frac {1-x}{1+x}$ . So, if $x\to 0$ then $t \to1$ and if  $x\to \infty$ then $t \to -1$ (at least for me)

Comment: You are misunderstanding, i am not seeking to solve the one from 0 to infinity but the one from 0 to 1 with said substitution

Comment: You just found that $\int_0^1 \frac{\ln 2}{1+t^2}dt=2\int_0^1 \frac{\ln(1+t)}{1+t^2}dt$ and also discovered that that substitution isn't useful for that integral.

Comment: If you want performing a change of variable try $x=\tan t$ and consider $\displaystyle A=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\cos t)dt,B=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\ln(\sin t)dt$

Comment: That means your subbing doesn't work for $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $x=\tan \theta$ yields

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x &=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln \left(\sec ^2 \theta\right) d \theta \\
&=-2 \int_0^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \ln (\cos \theta) d \theta \\
&=-2\left(-\frac{\pi}{4} \ln 2+\frac{1}{2} G\right) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2-G
\end{aligned}
$$

By my [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4360664/732917), $$\int_0^1 \frac{\ln \left(1+x^2\right)}{1+x^2} d x =\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2-G$$
where $G$ is the Catalan’s constant.